# How to know if I'm having WiFi micro-cuts?

Tags: wireless-networking, troubleshooting, internet-connection

When I navigate on my browser my WiFi connection seems to work alright. I can even see YouTube videos with no interruption.

However, everytime I want to play League of Legends or Fortnite (two online games), they tell me that connection has been lost as soon as the game window opens up (while, at the same time, I have access to websites with no inconveniences).

I suspect there might be micro-cuts taking place. Is there any way to confirm this, and (if possible) fix the issue?

Comment: It sounds more like games are being filtered and blocked than anything else. If there were some "micro-cut" then the games would work occasionally but sometimes drop, and it would likely happen to all programs. Speak to the people who provide your internet connection.

Comment: @Downvoters Why the downvotes? I think this is a perfectly valid question, as I'm asking for tools to test the connection and see if micro-cuts are taking place. What's wrong about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep pinging your router in the background while playing and such. When you feel connection issues, then pull up the ping result and see if there is any loss in pings. If there is, then it means that you're having a bad wireless signal.